# Call the values of a form from another component

Tags: angular

I want to call the values of the form I filled in another component but it gives me null values.

This is component 1 which contain the form :

```
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {
 lchartForm = this.fb.group({
 nb_columns: [],
 product_ID: [],
 indicator: [],
 startDate: [],
 endDate: [],

});
OnValidate() { 
this.router.navigate(['/Draw_Linechart']) }
OnSubmit() {..}
```

In the component1 html:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" 
  (click)= "OnSubmit();OnValidate()" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Submit</button>
```

And this is the component 2 :

```
export class DrawLinechartComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private linechartComponent: LineChartComponent) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.getProducts();}
getProducts() {
console.log("from the other component",this.linechartComponent.lchartForm.value)}
}
```

It gives me in the console :

```
{nb_columns: null, product_ID: null, indicator: null, startDate: null, endDate: null}
```

Can anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is communication between components. [There are several ways to do it](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/). Most common one being using services.

Example

Create a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  lchartForm: any; 
  constructor() { }
}
```

Add it as a provider in module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    LineChartComponent,
    DrawLinechartComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    DataService
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Inject it into your components and set/get the data from this service

```
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
 }
 OnValidate() { 
   // set data into data service variable
   this.dataService.lchartForm = this.lchartForm;
   this.router.navigate(['/Draw_Linechart']) 
  }
}
```

Retrieve data from service and use it:

```
export class DrawLinechartComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private linechartComponent: LineChartComponent, private dataService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.getProducts();
}

getProducts() {
 console.log("from the other component",this.dataService.lchartForm)}
}
```

Let us know if it helped.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data between components simply with injection, you have to find another way like using services or with @Input() decorators

Comment: I am trying to fix my problem with the most simple way ( I never worked with the Input decorator) How can I do it with the Input can you explain with code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the LineChartComponent as a provider in your app.module.ts file

```
providers:[LineChartComponent]
```

Also you need to add for each field of your FormBuilder in component1.html

```
<form [formGroup]="lchartForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
  <h3>LChart Form
</h3>

<label>
  NB_Columns:
  <input type="text" formControlName="nb_columns">
</label>
```

And so on for all fields
[image: Made field for NB_colums]

[image: Navigated to demoComponent and Output in Console]

Comment: thank you for replying but the problem doesn't resolved

Comment: Oh you have not declared field for input values in your component1.html.
You have to give input for nb_columns,product_Id ...etc
https://blog.logrocket.com/form-builders-angular-8-validate-reactive-forms/

Comment: It works only in component 1 but I want to call it from component 2 (it still giving me empty fields)

Comment: I have called the function from Component 2 (localhost:4200/demo) see console, its giving me the value.